# Im trying to set a range of integers based on the users input

Tags: java, string

SO i am trying to use the obtained integers in my Math.Random but i get java.lang.string error

```
int secretNum;
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Welcome to the guessing game. \n\nSet a range of numbers and the computer      will randomly generate a \nnumber between these numbers.Then you will try to guess the number!");
System.out.println("");
System.out.println("Please insert the lowest number in the range");
String low = input.nextLine();
System.out.println("Please insert the Maximum number in the range");
String max = input.nextLine();
secretNum = low + (int)(Math.random()*max);
```

Comment: max is a string, you need to convert it to an int. `Interger.parseInt(max)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`low` and `max` are Strings, so they can't be used in arithmetic operations. Convert them to integers before using arithmetic:

```
secretNum = Integer.parseInt(low) + (int)(Math.random()* Integer.parseInt(max));
```

You could also get integers using [`Scanner#nextInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()):

```
int low = input.nextInt();
int max = input.nextInt();
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of taking in the inputs as `String`, `low` and `max` should be ints, and therefore you could use

```
low = input.nextInt();
```

and

```
max = input.nextInt();
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare max not as String type but an Numeric(int or Integer) type. Like below

```
Integer max = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
```

and also for low too.